# How/where are actors defined in Oracle ATG for Rest API

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

My ATG installation has the Rest MVC enabled and a few actor chains registered in ActorChainRestRegistry.properties.

After looking through the Oracle ATG Rest API documentation I found a reference to atg.commerce.sitemap.CatalogSitemapGenerator, which I would like to be able to use.

I notice that the other entries in ActorChainRestRegistry have an Actor listed in their actor chains but I can't seem to figure out where these are defined.

in short, how can I implement atg.commerce.sitemap.CatalogSitemapGenerator as a REST API endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the config path define a *BlehActor.properties* and a *BlehActor.xml* (Replace *Bleh* with your actor name, of course.

This should match the actor name in your URL in the ActorChainRestRegistry.properties

In the properties file basically define:

```
$class=atg.service.actor.ActorChainService
definitionFile=/your/config/location/BlehActor.xml
```

BlehActor.xml is your chain definitions.